# Why does the $\delta$ term exist in the density-density correlation for simple liquids?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, liquid-state

I am reading *Theory of Simple Liquids* by Hansen and McDonald, and they in chapter 3, they describe the density-density correlation for a simple liquid in the grand canonical ensemble. This is how they have defined it:
$$H^{(2)}(r,r') = \langle [\rho (r) - \langle \rho (r) \rangle ][ \rho (r') - \langle \rho (r') \rangle ]\rangle $$
$$ = \rho ^{(2)}(r,r') - \rho ^{(1)}(r)\rho ^{(1)}(r') + \rho ^{(1)}(r) \delta (r-r').$$
This is my understanding of where the terms in the RHS comes from. I understand that the two-particle density $\rho^{(2)}$ term arises from:
$$\langle \rho (r) \rho (r') \rangle$$
in the RHS.

The second term in the RHS comes from expanding the the product and taking like terms together.

$$-\rho ^{(1)}(r)\rho ^{(1)}(r') = -\langle \rho(r) \langle \rho (r') \rangle \rangle - \langle \rho(r') \langle \rho (r) \rangle \rangle + \rho ^{(1)}(r) \rho ^{(1)}(r'),$$
where $\rho^{(1)}(r)$ is the average single-particle density at $r$, for a homogeneous liquid.

But I still do not get why that $\delta$-function exists there. Is the $\delta$-function just there to say that if the two particles are in the same spot ($r=r'$), the density correlation is... maximized? How does the $\delta$ fall out of the averaging, mathematically?

I would appreciate any advice you have for me!

Comment: Is this a classical or quantum liquid?

Comment: This is a classical liquid @march

Answer (score 2):

This is formal trickery and Hansen & Mc Donald are quite the wizards in this area... It is a matter of definition, whether we want the two point correlation function to include self interaction or not.

The third and last term correspond to $\langle \rho(r)\rho(r') \rangle$.
You have:
\begin{split}
\langle \rho(r)\rho(r') \rangle &=\left\langle \sum_i \sum_j\delta(r_i-r) \delta(r_j-r')\right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle \sum_i \sum_{j\neq i}\delta(r_i-r) \delta(r_j-r')\right\rangle +\left\langle \sum_i \delta(r_i-r) \delta(r_i-r')\right\rangle \\
&=\left\langle \sum_i \sum_{j\neq i}\delta(r_i-r) \delta(r_j-r')\right\rangle +\left\langle \sum_i \delta(r_i-r)\right\rangle\delta(r-r') \\
&=\rho^2(r,r') + \rho^1(r)\delta(r-r')
\end{split}

Where we used the identity $\delta(r-r_i)f(r)=\delta(r
-r_i)f(r_i)$ and the fact that for $\rho^2$, we don't sum over the same atom twice. The same kind of issues arise for the structure factor for example